# Characterization of Parseval Frame

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $e_j\in H$ for every $j\in\mathbb N$.

Is it possible to show that

$$\left\|f\right\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left|\langle f,e_j\rangle\right|^2\text{ for every }f\in H\text{ if and only if }f=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j\text{ for every }f\in H\tag*{?}$$

I get the feeling that we need $e_j\perp e_k$ if $j\neq k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the reverse implication [see this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/167340/22857).

Note that orthogonality is not required for a Parseval Frame.

Assume that $\|f\|^2=\sum_j|\langle f,e_j\rangle|^2$ for all $f$. Given $m>n$,
\begin{align}
\Big\|\sum_{j=1}^m\langle f,e_j\rangle\,e_j-\sum_{j=1}^n\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j\Big\|^2
&=\Big\|\sum_{j=n+1}^m\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j\Big\|^2\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\Big\{\Big|\Big\langle\sum_{j=n+1}^m\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j,h\Big\rangle\Big|:\ \|h\|=1\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\Big\{\Big|\sum_{j=n+1}^m\Big\langle\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j,h\Big\rangle\Big|:\ \|h\|=1\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\sup\Big\{\sum_{j=n+1}^m|\langle f,e_j\rangle\,\langle e_j,h\rangle|:\ \|h\|=1\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\bigg(\sum_{j=n+1}^m|\langle f,e_j\rangle|^2\bigg)^{1/2}
\sup\Big\{\bigg(\sum_{j=n+1}^m|\langle e_j,h\rangle|^2\bigg)^{1/2}:\ \|h\|=1\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\bigg(\sum_{j=n+1}^m|\langle f,e_j\rangle|^2\bigg)^{1/2}
\sup\Big\{\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^\infty|\langle e_j,h\rangle|^2\bigg)^{1/2}:\ \|h\|=1\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\bigg(\sum_{j=n+1}^m|\langle f,e_j\rangle|^2\bigg)^{1/2}.
\end{align}
The convergence of $\sum_j|\langle f,e_j\rangle|^2$ guarantees that the last series can be made arbitrarily small if $m$ and $n$ are large enough. So
$$
\sum_j\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j
$$
exists. Now we need to show that it equals $f$. We will need the Polarization Identity
$$
\langle f,g\rangle=\tfrac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\|f+i^kg\|^2,
$$
and also the particular case to complex numbers,
$$
z\overline w=\tfrac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k|z+i^kw|^2.
$$
We have
\begin{align}
\langle f,g\rangle&=\tfrac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\|f+i^kg\|^2
=\tfrac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\sum_j|\langle f+i^kg,e_j\rangle|^2\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_j\tfrac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k|\langle f,e_j\rangle+i^k\langle g,e_j\rangle|^2\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_j\langle f,e_j\rangle\langle e_j,g\rangle.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\Big\langle f-\sum_j\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j,g\Big\rangle
&=\langle f,g\rangle-\sum_j\langle f,e_j\rangle\langle e_j,g\rangle=0.
\end{align}
As this can be done for any $g$, it follows that
$$
f=\sum_j\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j. 
$$

Comment: The counterexample seems to contradict standard books on frame theory. According to e.g. Theorem 3.2.3 in Christensen's "An introduction to frames and Riesz bases", if $\{ e_n \}$ is a Bessel sequence (i.e. an upper frame bound exists but not necessarily a lower), then $\sum_n c_n e_n$ converges unconditionally in norm for all $\{ c_n \} \in \ell^2$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I have rewritten the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to assume orthogonality. The claim becomes more clear in terms of the *analysis operator* (aka Bessel operator)
$$ 
Af = (\langle f, e_j\rangle)_j 
$$
and the *synthesis operator* (aka reconstruction operator)
$$
S(c_j) = \sum_j c_j e_j
$$

The claim is that $SA=I$ if and only if $A$ is an isometry into $\ell^2$.

Proof or $\impliedby$. 
Suppose $A$ is an isometry into $\ell^2$. Then its adjoint $A^*$ is a bounded operator from $\ell^2$ to $H$, which agrees with $S$ because 
$$\langle Af, x\rangle_{\ell^2} =\sum_j \langle f, e_j\rangle_H \overline{x_j} =  
\left\langle f, \sum_j x_je_j\right\rangle_H = \langle f, Sx\rangle_H
$$
By the polarization identity, $\langle Af, Ag\rangle_{\ell^2} = \langle f, g\rangle_H $ for all $f,g\in H$. Hence $\langle A^*Af, g\rangle_H = \langle f, g\rangle_H $ for all $f,g\in H$, which implies $A^*A=I$. Since $A^*=S$, we conclude that $SA=I$.

Proof of $\implies$. Here I have to **assume that $A$ is a bounded operator into $\ell^2$**; it may be possible to remove this assumption, but I don't see how; in any case it is  standard in frame theory. As above, we have $S=A^*$. Since $SA=I$, it follows that $A*Af=f$ for every $f\in H$, hence 
$$
\|Af\|^2 = \langle Af, Af\rangle_{\ell^2} = \langle A^*Af, f\rangle_H = \langle f, f\rangle _H = \|f\|^2
$$
as desired.

Answer (score -1):

If $(e_j)$ is a sequence in $H$ with $<e_j,e_k>=\delta_{jk}$, then we have:

$(e_j)$ is an orthonormalbasis of $H$ $ \iff$

$\left\|f\right\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left|\langle f,e_j\rangle\right|^2\text{ for every }f\in H \iff\sum_{j=1}^\infty\langle f,e_j\rangle e_j\text{ for every }f\in H\tag*{}$

Comment: I was wondering if we can show this for arbitrary $(e_j)$.